# Accessing fonts in different directory

Tags: css

I have this code in a CSS file labeled "fonts.css" in the root directory of my website:

```
@font-face
{
    src:url(Fonts/Champagne%20&%20Limousines.ttf);
    font-family:'Champagne';
}

@font-face
{
    src:url(Fonts/Cicle%20Fina.ttf);
    font-family:'Ciclef';
}
```

I have all my fonts in a folder labeled "Fonts" in my root directory ("RootDirectory/Fonts").  The fonts work fine when I'm trying to access them with an HTML/CSS page located in the root directory.  However, when I try to access them from a page not in the root directory (it is "RootDirectory/About"), the fonts don't work.  I have some HTML of the page that's not working like this (linking to the "fonts.css" file):

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../fonts.css" />
```

It should be working, right?  It can't be a typo because I copied the new HTML and CSS directly from the 1st page who's fonts were working.

P.S. that's the only thing that isn't working in the new page, images and everything else are working fine.

Comment: Is this public?  Can you post a link?

Comment: Never mind.  I just uploaded it to a server and it's working on there.  Just not on my local file...  odd, but whatever.

Comment: I'm seeing the same strange behavior. Good to know it's only on my PC.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you know what you're doing, you should root local urls by specifying their whole path from the the document root.  This is done by prepending a slash to the url.

So..

```
src:url(Fonts/Champagne%20&%20Limousines.ttf); /*and*/
src:url(Fonts/Cicle%20Fina.ttf);
```

Become...

```
src:url(/Fonts/Champagne%20&%20Limousines.ttf); /*and*/
src:url(/Fonts/Cicle%20Fina.ttf);
```

And...

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../fonts.css" />
```

Becomes...

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/fonts.css" />
```

The leading slash means it's relative to the doc root of the website.  it also means it will work from on your website.  This makes it easier to reuse and reorganize your code.

Comment: Tried that, didn't work.  The CSS of the second document (the one not working right) is in the root directory, and I have the HTML linking to it correctly.

Comment: Then try your link tag, you said fonts.css is in the root dir right?  Then it should be `<link rel="stylesheet" href="/fonts.css" />`.  Can you confirm with firebug or something similar if the fonts file is loaded at all.

Answer (score 0):

Please try to cancel the spaces in your path and get rid of the %20. Also remove the ampersand &. What is the result?